# "Error: No connection info returned" when attempting to connect to SQL Server from Azure Data Studio

Tags: azure-data-studio

I am trying to understand what is wrong with connection parameters but there is no useful information provided. The connection string is:

> DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=test_db;PORT=1433;UID=sa;PWD=Some_password.123;

[image]
The "Details" are not helpful:

```
    at el.connect (vscode-file://vscode-app/Users/stephenboesch/Downloads/Azure%20Data%20Studio.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:4028:110964) [<root>]
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) [<root>]
    at async n.validateConnection (vscode-file://vscode-app/Users/stephenboesch/Downloads/Azure%20Data%20Studio.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:4028:120619) [<root>]
    at async y.handleOnConnect (vscode-file://vscode-app/Users/stephenboesch/Downloads/Azure%20Data%20Studio.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:4028:124826) [<root>]
    at async vscode-file://vscode-app/Users/stephenboesch/Downloads/Azure%20Data%20Studio.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:4028:132154 [<root>]
```

Comment: Could you please enable ODBC tracing and capture detailed logs so we can help you further troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: @Oury-MSFT Thanks for that info I did not know about `ODBC tracing`.  I will do so if this problem arises again: i had to pivot.